# How can I automatically detect if any deployment is running in a sandbox?

Tags: deployment, cicd, pipelines

I have several sandboxes available that my Azure DevOps pipeline can deploy to.

I want my pipeline to check each sandbox to see if there is a deployment running.  If there is, try the next one, if not, deploy there.

I can't find any standard object or metadata that will tell me whether there is any deployment running or not.

Anyone have any suggestions on this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DeployRequest` can be queried using `Tooling API`. When a deployment is running Status will be equal to InProgress. Below query can be used to understand if there is an in progress deployment against an org.

```
SELECT Id, Status, StartDate, CompletedDate FROM DeployRequest WHERE Status = 'InProgress'
```

For invoking from sfdx:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id, Status, StartDate, CompletedDate FROM DeployRequest WHERE Status = 'InProgress'" -t
```

While there is no documentation around the object (that I could find) it appears to be added in [Summer 20 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_api_tooling_new_and_changed_objects.htm).